# is this PHP ads revenue sharing logic valid?

Tags: php, algorithm, math

I'm adding in my website an Ads revenue sharing system, I built everything, for the ads sharing logic

```
$random_number = mt_rand(1,10);

if (($random_number >= 1) && ($random_number < 8)) { //gets 1-7 for 70%
$ads = "USER-ADS";
}

if (($random_number >= 8) && ($random_number < 11)) { //gets 8,9, and 10 for 30%
$ads = "ADMIN-ADS";
}
```

Is this logic is valid?

I want to show the user Ads to 70% of the pageviews, and show my ads for the remaining 30%

Comment: Looks good to me, the logic is sound.

Comment: You can simplify it a little though: `if (mt_rand(1,10) < 8) {$ads = "USER-ADS";} else { $ads = "ADMIN-ADS"; }` since `mt_rand(1,10)` is _guaranteed_ not to produce a number < 1 or > 10.

Comment: Even shorter with a ternary: `$ads = mt_rand(1, 10) < 8 ? "USER-ADS" : "ADMIN-ADS";`

Comment: Thanks Michael for validating the logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic looks good. You could use

```
if ($random_number < 8) {
$ads = 'USER-ADS';
} elseif ($random_number >= 8) {
$ads = 'ADMIN-ADS';
}
```

as it's a bit more compact and (trivially) faster.